# Remove Free shipping option

Tags: shipping, dropdown-attribute, sort, tags

Not sure how to remove free shipping option from sort by options.

[image: pic]

There is currently no free shipping products but it picks up all products, hence misleading.

Thanks

Comment: Add the magento vesion and other details.

Comment: Is there any product attribute named "Free Shipping"?

Answer (score 0):

If you have any free shipping attribute then Please change the below settings.

> System > Product
>   Search attribute **"Free shopping"** and edit that, From storefront Properties Set the configuration **Used for Sorting in Product Listing value** to **"NO"**

I hope it will be helpful to you...

Answer (score 0):

You can also just hide that through css. Find the class through inspect and hide it in your css file.